# Change country for app in Windows Store

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-store, regional-settings

How can I change the country for an app in the Windows Store if the app already exists in the store?
I want to remove a one country from the app on the Store. Is it possible without deleting the app from the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new release. Change the languages/countries. You shouldn't need to re-upload the app package. Submit the release.